# ElasticSearch querying nested objects not return result

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this object stored like this

```
{
  "_index": "sessions_user_dev",
  "_type": "user",
  "_id": "322",
  "_version": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": 322,
    "createdAt":        "2015-07-09T00:12:45+00:00",
    "firstName": "Amy",
    "lastName": "John",
    "openLocations": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "code": "QLD",
      "label": "Queensland",
      "country": "AU"
    }
    ]
  }  
}
```

And I would like to set a term for the openLocations and here is my code

```
{
    "query": {
    "term": {
        "user.openLocations.code": {
        "value": "QLD"
        }
        }
    }
}
```

But it always return zero result. I have also tried to change the field to openLocations.code without user infront but still no luck. Also tried:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
        "filter": {
        "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "term": {
                "openLocations.code": "QLD"
            }
        }
        ]
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

But still no result. Have tried to use nested query but it always say [nested] failed to find nested object under path [user.openLocations].

My Elasticsearch 5.4

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

What is the mapping of `openLocations.code`? It should be not analyzed if you want to use a term query, since this type of query will look up the exact value from the index.